# Can Google somehow gain access to data which is encrypted-at-rest with a CSEK in GCP?

Tags: google-app-engine, encryption, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-platform

We'd like to store sensitive health data using Google Cloud Storage. [Customer-Supplied Encryption Keys](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/using-encryption-keys) seem to provide a solution to securely store data in the cloud so that only we, the customer, might decrypt and read it. We would like to know more about this:

Are there any chances or possibilities that Google, the US Government or someone else could gain access to the decrypted sensitive data by legal means? For instance, can the GCP operators be forced somehow to extract the CSEK during runtime and use it to decrypt the storage data and/or share it with a third party? How are Law Enforcement Requests dealt concerning CSEK-encrypted data on the GCP?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"*Are there any chances or possibilities that Google, the US Government or someone else could gain access to the decrypted sensitive data by legal means?*" -- Absolutely.

Understand that companies like Google are strongly opposed to disclosing user data: it works against their business model, which relies on end user trust.  They go to enormous efforts to make sure that your data is protected and not even internal employees should have access to it.  But, when confronted with a court order, they have a requirement to comply.

Ever since the Snowden revelations, Google, Microsoft, Amazon, and others have been requesting permission from the US government to allow them to be more transparent about when private data is handed over to government authorities.  The [Google Transparency Report](https://www.google.com/transparencyreport/userdatarequests/legalprocess/) is an excellent source for information about how Google handles legal requests for end user data.

As for your specific question about CSEK, as long as your key is uploaded to Google's server, there is the chance that a law enforcement request can demand that certain data encrypted under that key is provided to them.

What would be ideal is if you could store your data in the cloud and do computations on that encrypted data in the cloud to get the information you want without handing your key over to the cloud service provider, thus preventing law enforcement from access your data without directly going to you.  There is a concept in cryptography research called [Homomorphic Encryption](https://blog.cryptographyengineering.com/2012/01/02/very-casual-introduction-to-fully/) that allows this to happen.  Unfortunately, it is nowhere close to practical right now.  A similar concept but more practical approach is [Mylar](https://eprint.iacr.org/2016/893.pdf), but unfortunately recent research has found some shortcomings in the security claims.  So, the technology is not quite ready to do what you and many others want: securing data in the cloud (+ the ability for the cloud provider to do useful things with it on your behalf) without handing over cryptographic keys.

Comment: I've accepted your answer, because it makes clear that Google might have to hand over data in case of law enforcement (+ link to transparency report), and because it provides links to interesting concepts for "ideal" solutions. Thanks! Does anyone know, if is there  an official statement from Google regarding this topic (handing over of user data to government authorities)?

Answer (score 2):

Cloud Storage does not permanently store your key on Google's servers or otherwise manage your key. Instead, you provide your key for each Cloud Storage operation, and your key is purged from Google's servers after the operation is complete. Once this has been done, your data is completely unreadable by Google or by anyone else who cannot break AES-256 encryption.

I can't speculate on what Google could or couldn't be forced to do by a government in the future. If you have any specific concerns, you should reach out to Google directly.

Comment: I have no experience with CSEK, but the statement "you provide your key for each Cloud Storage operation, and your key is purged from Google's servers after the operation is complete" relies on trusting Google, and [Google can be forced by law enforcement](https://www.google.com/transparencyreport/userdatarequests/) to do things that they do not in principle agree with.  Recommend the original poster read about [Lavabit](https://www.theguardian.com/world/2013/oct/03/lavabit-ladar-levison-fbi-encryption-keys-snowden) for examples of what governments may request.

Comment: "If you have any specific concerns, you should reach out to Google directly." - I have asked Google the same questions a week ago via their [contact form](https://cloud.google.com/contact/), but haven't got an answer yet. Maybe there is a better way to ask someone at Google? Anyway, I'll post it here, when I get an official answer.

Answer (score 2):

I know its a bit dated thread, but there is a clear answer from Google itself what does CSEK mean in terms of law enforcement requests:

> Where Google does not have ongoing access to the keys we would produce
> ciphertext in response to a request for stored data encrypted with a
> customer-supplied key.